# Passing data from java to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I am working on struts and I am trying to pass a String value from a java file to a jsp page. But I am receiving a null value. Please help.

My java code :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.struts.action.Action;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;

public class myAction extends Action {
    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
    HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IOException, ServletException {

        String s="Karthikeyan";

        request.setAttribute("s",s);

        RequestDispatcher reqDispatcher = getRequestDispatcher("first.jsp");
        reqDispatcher.forward(request,response);        

        return (mapping.findForward("success"));
    }
}
```

My jsp code :

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>

    <body>
        Welcome!!!!!!!!

        <%
            String s=(String)request.getAttribute("s");
            out.println("s="+s);
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

My jsp output :

```
Welcome!!!!!!!! s=null
```

I wanted to know why 's' is not getting assigned. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: by any chance any message in console

Comment: It doesn't make sense in the first place; why are you forwarding to a JSP *and* returning an action mapping (with superfluous parens)? And why use scriptlets? And why use Struts 1? In any case, which JSP are you even showing us? `first.jsp` or the JSP in your action's configuration? Bah.

Comment: @DaveNewton Actually I am trying to build a struts application. I am just trying to pass a string value from a java file to jsp. The code shown is first.jsp.

Comment: Show the action making and the URL you're hitting for the action processing. Have you verified your action is running?

Comment: @DaveNewton my struts-config.xml contains-                    <action path="/view" type="myAction" parameter="methodToCall" validate="false">
<forward name="success" path="first.jsp" />                
</action> --view.jsp is just a welcome file. The url is localhost:8080/MyProj/first.do

Comment: `first.do` isn't what your struts config shows, and you shouldn't forward to a JSP, instead, you should use only the action forward. Clean up your app first, then post a complete, minimal, failing, example.

Comment: I modified the struts-config.xml as follow. Sitll not working.
<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.1//EN" "http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/dtds/struts-config_1_1.dtd">
<struts-config>
    <action-mappings>
  <action path="/view" type="myAction" validate="false">
    <forward name="success" path="first" />
  </action>
  <action path="/view" forward="/view.jsp"/>
        <action path="/first" forward="/first.jsp"/>
    </action-mappings>
</struts-config>

Comment: Can you check with an IDE if the request obeject will be recreated (look for the object id)?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing

```
<%
   String s=(String)request.getAttribute("s");
   out.println("s="+s);
%>
```

Try to replace the whole thing with:

```
s=${s}
```